# Force new row of author names

Tags: titles, author

I have a list of 4 authors names using the `author`, and I would like force LaTex to place two on the first row and two on the second row. As it stands, I get three on the first row and one on the second.

How do I get the second row to start with the third author?

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Jane Doe 1\\
University of Illinois\\ Urbana-Champaign\\ 
\and John Doe 2\\
University of Illinois\\ Urbana-Champaign\\ 
\and John Doe 3\\
University of Illinois\\ Urbana-Champaign
\and John Doe 4\\
University of Illinois\\ Urbana-Champaign}
\date{}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: new row of authors]

Comment: If they really are all of the same uniersity, i would add that information just once. If this is not the case and the example is just an example; nevermind.

Comment: Yes, they have different affiliations. This was just for the purpose of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to use a tabular :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \shortstack{Jane Doe 1\\
    University of Illinois\\ Urbana-Champaign}
 &
   \shortstack{John Doe 2\\
    University of Illinois\\ Urbana-Champaign} \\ 
    \shortstack{John Doe 3\\
    University of Illinois\\ Urbana-Champaign}
 &
   \shortstack{John Doe 4\\
    University of Illinois\\ Urbana-Champaign}
\end{tabular}
    }
\date{}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably you should add some space between the lines of the tabular (like in the original picture).

Comment: No, not with `\shortstack`: avoid it; you should do another tabular.